# Typings install not working for already configured typescript definitions

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I have typings.json file with declarations to include some of the typescript definitions required for my project. Check reference below

```
...
"ambientDependencies": {
    "bluebird": "registry:dt/bluebird#2.0.0+20160319051630",
    "express": "registry:dt/express#4.0.0+20160317120654",
    "express-serve-static-core": "registry:dt/express-serve-static-core#0.0.0+20160322035842",
...
```

But when I try to execute `typings install` command nothing gets installed and typescript issues following statement

```
--- (No dependencies)
```

Unlike `npm install` which installs packages from `package.json`, the typings command is not working as expected. Am I having a wrong assumption? Till now I have avoided check-in of the typescript definitions (stored inside `typings` folder) in version control (like `node_modules`). Is it necessary to check-in this files?

**UPDATE**
It was my mistake, I update the `typings` command line utility to version `1.0.5`. I checked the https://github.com/typings/typings and realized that I need to change the typings.json to work with new major version. changed the `typings.json` as per the instructions given on the site and it is working now.

Comment: Which version of typings? Have you recently upgraded from pre-1.0 to post-1.0? Did you add the typings via typings itself, or by editing the JSON directly?

Comment: I have added the definition using `typings install XXX --save --ambient` command. None of the dependencies are handcoded. The typings version is 1.0.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've added the definitions using 0.x version of typings.
`--ambient` command is deprecated. Use `--global` instead.
In order to fix existing `typings.json` file you can rename "ambientDependencies" to "globalDependencies"